# Python: turtle or tkinter does not understand UP

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

So, I start to write a pong, and write this:

```
# teste de python, criando um pong, basicaly

#screen
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title('pong by dagashy')
wn.bgcolor('black')
wn.setup(width = 800, height = 600)
wn.tracer(0)

# paddle a
paddlea = turtle.Turtle()
paddlea.speed(0)
paddlea.shape('square')
paddlea.color('white')
paddlea.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddlea.penup()
paddlea.goto(-350,0)

# paddle b
paddleb = turtle.Turtle()
paddleb.speed(0)
paddleb.shape('square')
paddleb.color('white')
paddleb.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddleb.penup()
paddleb.goto(350,0)

# ball
ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
ball.shape('square')
ball.color('white')
ball.penup()
ball.goto(0,0)

# function
def paddleaup():
    y = paddlea.ycor()
    y += 20
    paddlea.sety(y)

def paddleadown():
    y = paddlea.ycor()
    y -= 20
    paddlea.sety(y)

def paddlebup():
    y = paddleb.ycor()
    y += 20
    paddleb.sety(y)

def paddlebdown():
    y = paddleb.ycor()
    y -= 20
    paddleb.sety(y)

# keyboard binding
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(paddleaup, 'w')
wn.onkeypress(paddleadown, 's')
wn.onkey(paddlebup, 'UP')
wn.onkeypress(paddlebdown, 'DOWN')



# screen loop
while True:
    wn.update()
```

And then, I run in the terminal with python and bum, this error shows up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/rodri/Desktop/Python/pong/index.py", line 63, in <module>
    wn.onkey(paddlebup, 'UP')
  File "C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\turtle.py", line 1394, in onkey
    self._onkeyrelease(fun, key)
  File "C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\turtle.py", line 687, in _onkeyrelease
    self.cv.bind("<KeyRelease-%s>" % key, eventfun)
  File "C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\turtle.py", line 416, in bind
    self._canvas.bind(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1251, in bind
    return self._bind(('bind', self._w), sequence, func, add)
  File "C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1206, in _bind
    self.tk.call(what + (sequence, cmd))
_tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "UP"
```

Tried to find anything like this, but anyone have no problem at all with key binding and key on press on internet, and if i try to find some with the final error, show up with something from tkinter, and i need help with turtle

edit: i went on turtle docs to find some key symbols, to see if UP is wrong, but i find nothing at all

Comment: `wn.onkey(paddlebup, 'UP')` should be `wn.onkey(paddlebup, 'Up')`. Notice the lowercase 'p'. Same thing with "DOWN" -> "Down"

Comment: oohh, really thanks to you man